# File download: don't works always - browser or server-side problem?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a routine in a controller to export data from the database to a specific format (`.xml`).

The routine looks like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ExportXml(IFormCollection form)   // Exports to .xml
        {
            OrdBasicInfo[] obi = GatherFormBasicInfoOrd(Request.Form);

            if (... some condition on obi ...)
            {
                 ModelState.AddModelError("oTable", "Error!");
                 return ListOrders(currPage); // an IActionResult ...
            }
           
            if (... some condition on obi ...)
                return RedirectToAction(...);

            // export to .xml 
            ExportXMLModel e = new ExportXMLModel(obi);

            return File(e.XMLContents /* a byte[] */, "text/xml", "xmlfile.xml");
        }
```

The models are irrelevant, I suppose: `e.XMLContents` is the `byte[]` with the xml contents.

In the View this is a simple submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Export XML" class="btn btn-primary btn-itf" asp-action="ExportXml" asp-controller="My" />
```

Why does this routine fails systematically when downloading to the front-end browser (MS Edge - v. 94.0.992.31, Firefox)?  Other times, it succeeds... It seems to be a browser-side problem.

May the encoding of the `byte[]` `e.XMLContents` cause a failure when being processed by the system?

**EDIT:**

May the download of this `xml` file, as done in the app, be interpreted by the browser as a "malicious download" (MS Edge: via Microsoft Defender SmartScreen)? Should the browser issue a warning?

Is this way of download state-of-the-art?

**EDIT 2:**

The code in the html is:

```
<form action="/Manage/ListOrders?page=1" class="form-group" method="post">

... several submit buttons with different formactions ...

<input type="submit" value="Export XML" class="btn btn-primary btn-itf" id="ExportBtnXml" formaction="/Manage/ExportXml">
<input type="submit" value="Export XLS" class="btn btn-primary btn-itf" id="ExportBtnXlsx" formaction="/Manage/ExportXlsx">

</form>
```

Is this html code ok? Or two actions are triggered on click (ListOrders included)? Both routines ExportXml and ExportXlsx return a file.

Comment: In what way does it fail?

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler or the browser's developer tools to look at the HTTP request and response. That will tell you if it's client or server-side.

Comment: The HTTP response isn't received (or well received) by the browser (MS Edge, Firefox)... Are you telling that this shouldn't fail and it satisfactorily programmed? That is an advance...

Comment: I suppose the problem is the "if (... some condition on obi ...)" because the browser expect a byte array but you are sending something else? Can you well describe what you mean with "Fails"?

Answer (score 0):

this happens because of the chrome ad blocker
to see how to disable it follow the link [disable ad blocker](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/7632919?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)

Comment: That's a bit of a leap! How would that explain intermittent behaviour?

Comment: I mainly used MS Edge instead of Chrome.